# How to use unix domain socket for tor socks

Tags: tor, unix-sockets, socks5-proxy

I am trying to setup a unix socks socket for tor usage instead of port 9050 in the hopes to gain a tiny bit of performance. However I am getting the below error:

```
Oct 21 11:53:54 HOSTNAME Tor[992986]: Permissions on directory /var/lib/tor-shared are too permissive.
Oct 21 11:53:54 HOSTNAME Tor[992986]: Before Tor can create a SOCKS socket in "/var/lib/tor-shared/socks5.socket", the directory "/var/lib/tor-shared" needs to exist, and to be accessible only by the user account that is running Tor.  (On some Unix systems, anybody who can list a socket can connect to it, so Tor is being careful.)
```

Isn't the whole point of a SOCKS socket is to allow other apps to connect to it?

What is the best way to allow an app to use tor via unix domain socket? I don't think the application itself should run as User 'tor' or root. I tried `setfacl`, but tor is smart to not allow that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to explicitly allow everyone to connect.

```
SocksPort /var/lib/tor-shared/tor.socket WorldWritable
```

If using `tor@default.service` in debian or its derivatives (like ubuntu), there is already a WorldWritable socket configured at `/run/tor/socks`